# is there any fixed-left in bootsrap navigations?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzzch.png)I want to fix my navigation bar on the left side but the bootstrap only have fixed-top and fixed-bottom. Is there's any good source than can help ?

```html
           <!-- navigation -->            
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top leftside">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="kaleem.png" alt="" width="90px" height="90px">
              </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">EXPERIENCE</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">EDUCATION</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">SKILLS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">INTERESTS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">AWARDS</a>
                  </li>    
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </nav>
```

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: code added. i actually want the navbar to be fixed on left instead on top.